# Why I can not find "Debug Managed Memory" on Actions menu?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-leaks, dump, procmon

Why I can not find "Debug Managed Memory" on Action menu as described at this MSDN article: [Analyze .NET Framework memory issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx)?

My Visual Studio:
[image]

How it is supposed to look:
[image]

Comment: Maybe a silly question but do you have the same version of Visual Studio (2013)? Express edition? Maybe this is a new feature or is not included in the variant you have. Sorry if this is not the case, just asking the obvious I guess.

Comment: Could it be lacking due to Visual Studio version?

Comment: I tried on Visual Studio 2013 Premium and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. Same result. I collected the dump file using "D:\Temp>procdump -ma 9056"

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, the w3wp is just an example that I took from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx. The first screenshot is my Visual Studio. I'm trying to investigate a memory leak issue. The application is a WPF app.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In one of the related [articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production.aspx), two requirements are mentioned (emphasis added):

> Before I begin, there are a few things to note about the "Debug Managed Memory" feature discussed in this post:
>
> 1. The option will only be available from the dump summary page in the **Ultimate version of Visual Studio 2013**.  If you are using Premium or Professional you will not see the option.
> 2. **The process the dump file was collected against must have been running on .NET 4.5 or higher.**  If the dump was collected on 3.5 or previous the option will not appear, if it was collected on 4.0 it will fail to launch with an error message.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015, it seems to only be available in Enterprise edition.

Comment: In VS2019 that seems to be the same (available in Enterprise).

Comment: Btw you can download a free trial of Enterprise.  This feature is gold.