# Can't find Debug Managed Memory option. Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, debugging, sdl-2

I have been trying to fix a weird memory problem with my C++/SDL2 program. I want to use the **Debug Managed Memory**  feature in VS 2013 to compare two dump files I made, but the option is not there. I am using .NET 4.5 and VS 2013 Ultimate edition, so I don't know why the option wont show.

Many thanks to anyone who answers. Any theories (no matter how crazy) will help because I am clueless at this point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I can not find "Debug Managed Memory" on Actions menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241905/why-i-can-not-find-debug-managed-memory-on-actions-menu)

Comment: I have seen that question. The answers are irrelevant to me because I am already using .NET 4.5 and VS 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Is there actually any managed code at all in this program?  Neither C++ nor SDL2 give a strong lead that's the case.  If the Debug + Windows + Modules window doesn't contain clr.dll then fuggedaboudid.  If it does then tinker with the "Use Managed Compatibilty Mode" option.

Comment: Hans Passant, you are my hero. I forgot to enable CLR to make my code managed.