# Getting memory error trying to debug manage memory with a big minidump file

Tags: memory, visual-studio-2015, minidump, diagnostic-tools

I'm trying to "Debug Managed Memory" with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition. The file is at 1.2GB and after while loading I get the error message "Memory analysis could not be completed due to insufficient memory" after have been pressing "Debug Managed Memory"

What can I do to still be able to look into the memory with the pdb files? Can I start Visual Studio 2015 with more memory (the computer has 25 GB memory free) I guess it has to do with Visual Studio being running with x86.

Comment: You could analyze it with WinDbg

Comment: I know, but I rather not if possible.

Comment: One way is to create dmp file and analyze it with VS 2015 as written here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx  but here comes the problem that is only available for ultimate or enterprise as written here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241905/why-i-can-not-find-debug-managed-memory-on-actions-menu

Comment: @batmaci that is exactly what I try to do, but the dump file was to big.

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to VisualStudio bug

see the following link

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2621837/debug-managed-memory-for-10-gb-memory-dump-files

as a workaround they are suggesting about turning off automatic symbol loading before starting analyzing dumps (i.e. Tools -> Options ->Debugging -> Symbols -> Select "only specified modules")

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

This error not apperas when project compiled to x64 platform