# "Debug Managed Memory" not available for dump in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, memory-dump

I have a memory leak in a .NET application (a Windows service) in production. I have created a memory dump through Task Manager and now I want to evaluate that dump in my VS 2015 with regard to the number of managed objects.

I have only found how to do that for Visual Studio 2013, but not for VS 2015. [So I tried to use the tutorial for 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx#BKMK_Analyze_memory_use), but I don't have the "Debug Managed Memory" link in VS 2015.

On the left is my Visual Studio, on the right is the screenshot from the tutorial:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/pfhAJbU.png] 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgfPv.png]

How can I check the objects?

Comment: Consider googling "minidump debug managed memory".  The first hit looks pretty good.

Comment: @HansPassant Please provide a link, because Google has personalized/geographical results. In my Google search result for your very search string, the first hit is the very document I linked to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40091346/1559611

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I would love to get to that error as well (my dump is 850 MB while the expected size of the application should be 150 MB, so it's unlikely that I would hit a limit there), but I can't because I can't click the button in the first place. However, it seems to be available in VS 2015. But not in mine. Is it connected to the memory dump being a production dump? Can I only analyze debug dumps, or dumps from the same machine?

Comment: I actually use Windbg for dump analysis which has managed extensions too, the durable windows debugging tool for decades, if you are keen to consider

Comment: "debuggen nur verwaltet" means managed debugging.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have put the two screenshots next to each other for you to see that it isn't there.

Comment: Consider not making a dump through Task Manager, but using [`procdump -ma`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procdump). I'm not saying it's the only way to make dumps, but it's the one I've had the most success with across various versions of Windows to get full, debuggable dumps.

Comment: ok, now I see what is missing. good question.

Comment: Also consider not using VS, but WinDbg with SOS and [`!dumpheap -stat`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2005/11/25/dumpheap-stat-explained-debugging-net-leaks/) and `gcroot`. Bigger learning curve, but reliable. VS is more convenient when you're stepping through the code; its memory analysis is spotty.

Comment: I'm guessing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21241905/23074) @HansPassant was alluding to. Does that help?